# Quel est le français pour « Open Source » et/ou « Free/Libre Open Source Software » (F/LOSS)?

Tags: traduction, informatique

J'aimerais savoir le(s) mot(s) juste(s) pour « Open Source. »

Ce qui serait mieux encore, c'est d'avoir une traduction de l'expression « Free/Libre Open Source Software. »

Le mot « libre » est évidemment déjà du français (bravo M. Stallman), mais j'ai du mal à trouver une bonne traduction pour le reste.

Pour information : je préférerais une réponse autre que « on utilise tout simplement l’expression anglaise. » Si c'est le cas, veuillez donner votre meilleur effort.

Comment: Étant donné les exigences, peut-on savoir quel est le contexte dans lequel cette phrase doit-être utilisée, et pourquoi il est essentiel que ce ne soit pas "tout simplement l'expression anglaise" ?

Comment: Étant dégouté par l'invasion à grande échelle par la langue anglaise dans le français, j'essaie d'utiliser au maximum possible des termes français.

Comment: Le problème est je pense que le français n'a pas les mêmes capacités d'évolution rapides que l'anglais, et qu'utiliser un maximum de termes français juste pour le principe (respectable) pourrait largement compliquer le propos. Freeware et Shareware sont je pense bien plus faciles à utiliser que gratuiciel ou partagiciel. Je ne parle même pas du cédérom (qui perd tout de la signification de l'acronyme) ou même de l'arobase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« Logiciel libre » ou « Logiciel open source »

Wikipédia donne « logiciel à code source ouvert » mais ce n’est vraiment pas très courant.

On emploie souvent l’expression anglaise « open source » ;)

"Libre open source software" sounds like a pleonasm to me.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a pleonasm. However, Stallman's point in coining that phrase was to make explicit the fact that Free Software is free in the French sense of « libre » rather than the English sense of « gratuit » !

Comment: @Vérace In either the linguistic or the legal point of views, it is not a pleonasm. The word "Libre" is vague, it means there are no restrictions without specifying further, "Open source" means the source code is available without telling anything about the rights attached. In the legal point of view, "libre" means complying with the four FSF freedoms, "Open Source" means complying with the ten Open Source Initiative criteria. Most licenses complying with one currently comply with the other too but this is deliberate from their authors, not implicit per the rules. There are notable exceptions.

Comment: Je noterais tout simplement que pour Stallman, "Free" et "Libre" sont des synonymes - donc pour lui au moins, la phrase "Free/Libre and Open Source Software" **est** bien un pléonasme. Pour d'autres, il s'agit de leur(s) version(s) de "Free" et de "Libre".

Comment: @Vérace "Open source" a **exactement** le même sens que "libre" (ou free as beer…) si on s’en tient à la définition de l’OSI (https://opensource.org/). Il est vrai que beaucoup emploient le terme "open source" à tort, pour se donner une bonne image… Non il ne suffit pas que l’on puisse accéder au source pour que ce soit de l’open source ;)

Comment: Le pléonasme dont on parle est l'addition du mot "Libre" au mot "Free" dans la definition - pour Stallman, "Free" ou "Libre" entraîne automatiquement la nature ouverte du code source. Pour lui et compagnie, "Free/Libre" et "Open Source" est une tautologie. Pour les autres definitions que celle de la FSF, telles la [kyrielle](https://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical) de l'OSI ou d'autres organisations,  à vous le choix! :-)

Comment: @Stéphane "Open Source" n'a pas la même définition que "libre". L'OSI et la FSF sont des organisations avec des objectifs différents. Un logiciel satisfaisant aux dix critères de l'OSI n'est pas nécessairement conforme aux quatres libertés de la FSF.

Comment: @Vérace Le pléonasme dont on parlait au début était celui cité dans la réponse de Stéphane: *"Libre open source software" sounds like a pleonasm to me.* où *free* n'apparaît pas. L'addition du mot libre au mot *free* n'est pas pour moi un pléonasme mais au contraire une précision indispensable pour dissiper l'équivoque du terme *free*.

Answer (score 3):

On pourrait le traduire par « Logiciel libre à source ouvert. »

Autant l'expression « logiciel libre » est très répandue, autant je n'ai jamais entendu l'expression « source ouvert ».  Cela sonne maladroit, ou inhabituel, parce que l'expression « Open source » est très répandue.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais « **Logiciel libre et gratuit à code source ouvert** ».

« *Free* » est traduit par « **libre et gratuit** » ou seulement « **libre** » ou seulement « **gratuit** » pour respectivement « *free as in free beer and free speech* », « *free as in free speech* », « *free as in free beer* ».

Pour « open source » le plus utilisé est « **open source** » car le concept est bien identifié sous ce nom. On peut également dire « **code source ouvert** », ou plus clairement utiliser directement le nom de la licence comme par exemple « **code sous licence MIT** » ou « **code sous licence GPL3**. »

Answer (score 1):

Pour avoir une meilleure traduction, il faut savoir quel type d'open source il s'agit.

Le premier est celui dont le programme est distribué avec son code ouvert et modifiable. Ce type de logiciel libre (je reviens sur le terme plus loin) n'est pas nécessairement gratuit, mais la redistribution en est généralement possible.

L'autre type est plus similaire au projets qui trainent un peu partout. Ils sont sans licence et leurs codes sont modifiable dans un but commun.

Selon l'[office Québecois de la langue française](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/resultat.aspx?terme=open%20source), les deux types sont traduits comme cela:

> Logiciel libre (cas 1)
>
> Code source libre (cas 2)

Pourquoi `Logiciel libre`? Le `libre` réfère à l'absence de droits d'auteurs ou de contraintes de ce style (pour faire simple). Bref, après l’acquisition du logiciel tu est libre d'en faire ce que tu veux (ou presque).

Pour l'autre, il faut voir comme si il n'y a pas de distribution. Un peu comme n'importe quel bout de code trouvé sur StackOverflow.

Pour ce qui est d'avoir une traduction complète de `Free/Libre Open Source Software`, j'irais avec la traduction de abendhurt. Sinon juste `logiciel libre` devrait être implicite sur son sens.

Exemple:

> Par manque de ressources monétaires, nous avons dû nous tourner vers  des logiciels libres pour compléter ce projet.

Le site de [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.fr.html) contient des détails sur les logiciels libres qui peuvent être intéressant.

Modif: [Une image vaut mille mots](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/category.fr.png) même si elle n’amène rien à la traduction

Comment: Qu'entendez vous par "Sans licence" ? Une licence non restrictive du type "MIT" ? GNU General Public License ? [L'absence de Licence signifie que les lois classiques s'appliquent](http://choosealicense.com/no-license/).

Comment: Je dois avouer que mon utilisation de aucune licence est un peu tirée. Je voulais plus faire référence à des licences de types similaire au GPL. J'ai voulu être simple dans ma réponse, mais cela y fait probablement plus de mal.

Comment: La deuxième définition ne semble pas être celle des logiciels open source ou libres (qui ont tous un copyright ou droits d'auteur en France, et peuvent être payants), mais celle des logiciels du domain public.

Comment: @jiliagre Sans vouloir trop m'avancer de peur de me tromper, un logiciel du domaine public ne peut-il pas être aussi Open source? Si son code source est ouvert au modifications je crois qu'il rentre dans cette catégorie.

Comment: Oui, il l'est même toujours sauf si ses sources ne sont pas publiés, seulement des fichiers binaires. L'inverse n'est pas vrai. Une logiciel open source ou libre n'est pas nécessairement du domaine public et c'est même rarement le cas. En droit français, tout code publié est soumis aux droits d'auteur. Il faut que l'auteur abandonne explicitement ses droits pour que le logiciel devienne du domaine public.

Comment: @jlliagre Pour la deuxième définition, ils indiquent une sous catégorie (programmation) et ça donne l'impression qu'ils essayent de manier l'idée mais épurée de concepts juridiques ; je ne sais pas si c'est réussi. Ils ont aussi une entrée particulière pour [domaine public](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26534212). Leur première entrée est en fait celle de _Franceterme_. On hésite j'ai l'impression...